# Oracle - Ora 04068 and Pragma SERIALLY_REUSABLE

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am running an oracle job that will rename various table object during runtime and recompile the dependent packages to prevent an invalidation during the renaming process. However, I encountered several instances of Ora 04068 appearing.

Referencing the issues in stackoverflow, it is recommeded to use PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE on the dependent packages. Can anyone share in greater details how that is useful?

1) I am using parallel DML queries on the packages, will that pragma cause all queries to be run serially?

2) What are the implications of such a statement?

Many thanks in advance!